# SSIS Component In integration Package Fails to Run

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs a few file system tasks and has been running successfully without issue for month. Lately I updated a step to add an additional file system task, tested it to make sure the added component succeeds, and connected it to the existing branch.

What has happened since that update however is now the step directly proceeding that new component is failing to activate when I run the package. I've attached a screenshot of the specific package components, the Rename Prior Day's Files is the element that's now no longer activating whenever either of the preceding paths succeed. The package just stops at either the Rename or File System Task.

[image: SSIS screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand, the Foreach Container "Rename Prior Day's Files" is no longer lighting up.

There are two input paths to this container: "Rename ControlFileA to ControlFileB" as a Success *and* "File System Task" as Completion.

Note the emphasis on AND there. You are only going to get *one* of the paths out of the new rename task lighting up: Success or Failure. By the time the Failure to Completion path gets back to the loop container, it will only go green if both are true.

To resolve it, double click either the green or black completion path and change that from "Logical AND" to "Logical OR"  You'll notice they both switch to a dashed line at this point

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue, my branches were set to AND instead of OR for their input. My pathing never really had a need for that type of branch before and I didn't realize it needed to be updated in order to proceed. Much appreciated!